# sublime text 3 build - how to show versions of the build system?

Tags: python, sublimetext3

Hello When I use sublime text 3, with python, let's say 2.7.13, How do I get the build to output the version of python every time I run a python script?

Can I do that by add a command in the setting file?

it is currently set as (Python.sublime-build)

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "python -u \"$file\"",
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",

    "env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"},
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do this would be to modify the build so that it runs `python` twice, once to get it to print the version and a second to actually execute the script:

```json
{
    "shell_cmd": "python --version && python -u \"$file\"",
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",

    "env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"}
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to show me how to add a blank line between the python version and the actual output of the codes? Thanks!

Comment: I'd try adding in `&& echo` between the two pythons and see what that does.